# Can Authority Ruby Gem be used with logged out users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authority-gem

I get the following error:

```
  undefined method `can_read?' for nil:NilClass
```

..when trying to access a product page with a logged-out user. At the moment I have

```
class ProductAuthorizer < ApplicationAuthorizer

  def self.readable_by?(user)
    true
  end

end
```

I'd like to allow even non-logged in users to see the page. Is this possible?

I tried changing the default user method to:

```
config.user_method = :current_user ||= User.new
```

However, this causes problems, and my server won't even start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I found this at https://github.com/nathanl/authority/pull/32:

> OK! For the sake of anyone else reading this issue, Chris and I
>   chatted and agreed about the best way to proceed. Here's the gist of
>   it.
>
> Authority won't specially handle nil users or give a specific option
>   to do so. We want to limit Authority to authorization and keep
>   authentication totally separate. If there's no user signed in, that's
>   an authentication concern; Authority can't meaningfully answer the
>   question "can this user do X?" if it isn't given a user or something
>   that quacks like one.
>
> Besides the philosophical point, having authentication handle this is
>   a better user experience. If an admin has forgotten to sign in and
>   attempts some admin-only action, it would be confusing to them to say
>   "access denied". It would be much more helpful to say "please sign
>   in".
>
> What developers using Authority can do is:
>
> Have something like Devise's before_filter :authenticate_user! running
>   prior to any Authority checks on the request (since any action that
>   requires authorization clearly requires authentication). Have their
>   user method return a NullUser object that quacks like a user, then
>   have their authorizers know what to do with those What Authority can
>   do is improve the error it gives you if you pass nil or anything else
>   that doesn't quack like a user. Chris is going to implement this.

Hi I've just put this

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      def current_or_null_user
        if current_user == nil
          User.new
        else
          current_user
        end
     end
  end
```

...

```
Authority.configure do |config|
   config.user_method = :current_or_null_user
end
```